# ORM - ManyToMany relation on MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a classes as follows:

```
AnimalClass [Id, Name, Set<Tag>]
|
+-- FishClass [FishSpecific]
+-- MammalClass [MammalSpecific]

Tag [Name]
```

So any animal can have any number of associated tags.

For that I use in AnimalClass:

```
@JoinTable(name="Animal_Tag")
@JoinColumn(name="animal_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Getter
protected Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
```

My problem is that, Hibernate creates the m-n table as:

```
 Animal_Tag [FishClass_id, MammalClass_id, Tag_id].
```

I would prefer to have some kind of enumeration as:

```
 Animal_Tag [Animal_id, AnimalTypeEnumeration[ Fish | Mammal ], Tag_id].
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you can't do that with a mapped superclass.

The thing about a mapped superclass is that it doesn't define a persistent type. It defines a sort of template for a persistent types. Every time you define a subclass of it which is annotated `@Entity`, you create an instance of the template, but in the data model, there is no relationship between those types. The use of the mapped superclass is almost a shortcut for a copy-and-paste of a given set of fields into the new entity class.

So, as far as the data model is concerned, there is no possible animal_id, because there is no such type as animal. Only fish and mammal exist in the database.

Can you make `AnimalClass` an entity instead of a mapped superclass? If you use the table-per-class inheritance strategy, you won't need to create a table for it. But it will make animal a type, which means the ORM will be able to use an animal_id.

Comment: I can't use the superclass as @Entity, because the Schema is in fact far more complex (4 inherited classes which join other inherited classes). The problem is that what I am trying to achieve here is exactly the opposite of what I am trying to achieve with other parts of the class - here I want to have Animal_Tag, but in other variables I need exactly separated for inst. Fish_Photos and Mammal_Photos.

Comment: You could have separate fish and mammal photos by declaring the variables for them in the Fish and Mammal classes, rather than the base class. Can you have a mapped superclass which is a child of an entity? You could have an Animal entity, then a Vertebrate mapped superclass which extends it, then Fish and Animal extending that. This would be a bit contrived, but it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The table structure that you want would have a foreign key that can point to different tables, depending on the value of another field. I don't think any DB allows that.

Polymorphism with ORM is always tricky. Best thing to do is just avoid it if you can. Otherwise, maybe you could use `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)` on Animal? This would result in a table structure like this:

```
TABLE Animal
 - id (primary key)

TABLE Fish
 - id (foreign key -> Animal)
 - fins
 - scales

TABLE Mammal
 - id (foreign key -> Animal)
 - mammaries
```

Comment: By the way, I was talking about JPA annotations - I just noticed you're using Hibernate annotations. I have no idea what the Hibernate equivalent is.

Comment: JPA annotations are the same as for Hibernate. Please read the comment which I've written for the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be use "table per subclass wih discriminator" inheritance for AnimalClass? In case of hibernate it result fowing hirecaly:

```
AnimalClass [Id, AnimalTypeEnumeration (discriminator), Name]
|
+-- FishClass [FishSpecific]
+-- MammalClass [MammalSpecific]
Animal_Tag [Animal_id, Tag_id]
```

Comment: THe problem is that I can'T use the superclass as @Entity - please read my comment for Tom Anderson.